# Education consultant earnings are halal or not?

Tags: halal-haram, work

I am an education consultant. I make admissions of students in the colleges of their choices and charge them money of which all the money goes to the concerned college and I get only a small amount.some colleges take direct admission and some conduct examinations to short list the students. If a student is weak and cannot pass the examination then I make some other intelligent student give the examination on behalf of the weak student and after getting the result the weak student gets admission into the college. For this process, I charge the weak student money of which a greater part goes to the college and the intelligent student and I get only a small amount. Is this money haram for me? This process takes place with the knowledge and consent of the weak student,his/her parents,the intelligent student and sometimes the college concerned. but the colleges are not informed always due to security reasons.
Is my earning in this process haram? please help me.

Comment: "I make some other intelligent student give the examination on behalf of the weak student," isn't it obvious that this is cheating and therefore haraam? And, of course, illegal too.

Answer (score 1):

> If a student is weak and cannot pass the examination then I make some other intelligent student give the examination on behalf of the weak student and after getting the result the weak student gets admission into the college.

This part is Haram, totally unacceptable, and its cheating .

However, if you make money out of simply as a education consultant, helping students with their college, trying to bring the best out of them, I think there should not be any problem.This is because you are taking money for the time you spend, which you could have spent in some other profitable way.